# A binary sequence graph

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, combinations, connectedness

> Define a graph $H(n, 2)$ as follows. Each vertex corresponds to a
>   length $n$ binary sequence and two vertices are adjacent if and only if
>   they differ in exactly two positions.

I want to find three things.

(1) The number of vertices

(2) The degree of each vertex in this graph

(3) The number of connected components of this graph.

For (1) is really easy, It is just $2^n$ for example, if we have $n=2$ then we would have four vertices which are $$00$$
$$01$$
$$10$$
$$11$$

and for $n=3$ we would have $2^3$ and so on, so in general we would have $2^n$ vertices.

For (2) it's a bit tricky, We know that each binary sequence is adjacent to another binary sequence that differs in exactly two position so if we have $n=3$ then $$ 000 \longrightarrow 011,110,101 $$
and if we have $n=4$ then $$0000 \longrightarrow 0011,1100,0110,1001,1010,0101$$ and so in general it's $${n \choose 2}$$

Now I have a lot of troubles with (3), How can I find the number of connected components of this graph. I tried to see it visually with small numbers of $n=2$ an for $n=3$ we would have two connected components and also the same thing when $n=3$ we would also have two connected components , **this makes me thing that in general for any $n$ we would have two connected components But my question is why, I couldn't come up with an argument here.**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

HINT: Look at the parity of the number of $1$ bits of the vertices in each of the components that you found for small $n$.

**Added:** Say that a vertex is *even* if it has an even number of $1$ bits and *odd* otherwise. As a further hint, note that edges of $H(n,2)$ always connect vertices of the same parity.

Comment: what is the parity ?

Comment: @alkabary: The oddness or evenness of an integer. Two integers have the same parity if the are congruent modulo $2$, i.e., both odd or both even; otherwise they have opposite parities.

Comment: We have two evens and two odds in each of them ?

Comment: @alkabary: For both the $n=2$ and the $n=3$ case you have one component that has all of the vertices of even parity and one that has all of the vertices of odd parity. That’s not a coincidence. You should try to prove two things: (1) if two vertices of $H(n,2)$ have the same parity, there is a path between them; and (2) if they have opposite parity, there is no path between them. HINT: Edges always connect vertices of the same parity.

Comment: ahaaa, I think I got what you are saying now, parity meaning the number of ones appearing in a binary sequence, ok, Now (2) is easy , if two vertices have opposite parity then they there is no path between them because the number of different bits are different right ? But for (1), if two vertices have the same parity then this means that they have same number of different bits ?, I am kinda confused how to prove this

Comment: @alkabary: If two vertices have the same parity, they differ in an even number of places. Show that if they differ in $2k$ places, there's a path of length $k$ between them.