# Chromatic number of a graph on a binary alphabet

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, information-theory, coloring

given the graph defined in this post:
[A binary sequence graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1507078/a-binary-sequence-graph)

i.e.,
Define a graph $H(n,2)$ as follows. Each vertex corresponds to a length nn binary sequence and two vertices are adjacent if and only if they differ in exactly two positions.

how would one go about finding its chromatic number?

Comment: That definition is _two lines long_. Couldn't you be bothered to quote it here instead of just linking?

Comment: By constructing a coloring and show that it is optimal. Please show some effort.

Comment: Sorry, I added the definition

Answer (score 1):

Each sequence of length $n-1$ needs its own color and the last (parity) bit can be ignored, so: $$\chi(H_n) = 2^{n-1}$$

Enumerate the strings and colors and find that any sequence $X10Y$ has an edge in common with $X01Y$, similar for $X11Y$ and $X00Y$. This requires a new color.

The final bit does not need a new color.